# How to get only current day data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using MS Access to create a database that gets values ​​from an excel and accumulates them.

However, I want to create a query in Access that only inserts rows from the current day.
I created the following query, but it always inserts nothing in my Access database, as if in excel there were no values ​​for the current day.

```
INSERT INTO acc_table(Date, Name) 

SELECT Date, Name FROM excel_table

WHERE excel_table.Date=DATE();
```

Something is wrong in my query. Can someone help me?

Comment: What happens if you just run the SELECT statement? Do you get any rows back?

Comment: Date and Name are reserved words. Try enclosing field name in `[ ]`; `[Date], [Name]`. Advise not to use reserved words as field names

Comment: Are your dates U.S. or international (dd/mm/yyyy)? Access standard is mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if `excel_table.Date` holds *Date* values with no time part:

```sql
INSERT INTO acc_table ([Date], [Name]) 
SELECT [Date], [Name] FROM excel_table
WHERE excel_table.Date = Date();
```

If `excel_table.Date` has a time part or is *text*, try this:

```sql
INSERT INTO acc_table ([Date], [Name]) 
SELECT [Date], [Name] FROM excel_table
WHERE DateValue(excel_table.Date) = Date();
```